# App rejected on 11.13 (New user registration is not appropriate)

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, privacy

DTMF call mechanism is my app.To access the app's feature first the user needs to sign in. If the user is new without any account created he can even sign up. The reasons to get rejected are the following.

> 11.13
>
> We found that your app provides access to external mechanisms for
>   purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, which is not in
>   compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> New user registration is not appropriate. Please see the attached
>   screenshot/s for more information.
>
> To be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines, it would be
>   appropriate to remove the access to these mechanisms - including fully
>   qualified links to your site that could indirectly provide access to
>   these mechanisms, such as links to web pages for support, FAQ, product
>   or program details, etc.
>
> On occasion, there may be apps on the App Store that don't appear to
>   be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. We work hard to
>   ensure that the apps on the App Store are in compliance and we try to
>   identify any apps currently on the App Store that may not be. It takes
>   time to identify these occurrences but another app being out of
>   compliance is not a reason for your app to be.

Please help me by giving a solution for this problem. It will be very helpful if I could get the exact reason for rejecting my app.

Comment: I have not much reputation to upload the image.

Comment: upload the image in http://imageshack.us/ and then post the url

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to sell something, that could be part of your app. For that you should use the IAP api, that means 30% to Apple. You should demonstrate to them that what you sell is not a part of your application or a subscription service.

The whole 11 chapter of Apple store guidelines is about [purchasing](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies).

You must be really sure that what you are selling cannot be "part" of your application or you need to use In App Purchase.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments and guidance. I have send the mail as you said to the apple review team and right now I am waiting for their reply.

Answer (score 0):

Can the user sign up **within** the app?

If not (if the user needs to open a site to sign app) that is the problem.
You should add a signup procedure inside the app.

Comment: yes we have sign up page.New user can register through this.please tell me what did i wrong to reject this application

Comment: Ok, so if the user can register **only** through the site, that is the problem. "We found that your app provides access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions" --> you are in the last situation, an external mechanism for subscription

Comment: If you want to be sure, moreover, you can ask the review team (by responding to the rejection) if my solution is ok (they usually answer in 3-4 days)

Comment: No, Inside the application itself we can register. Currently we removed all the external mechanism and still got rejected ? Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Ok, the problem is not the registration. So look at @Andrea answer: can the users subscribe (paying) for additional services for the app through your website? If the answer is yes, you can only add that services through In App Purchase (leaving 30% to Apple) and remove the possibility to purchase it from the site for iOS users.